# Is it possible to route different applications through different network interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking

Is it possible to route different applications through different network interfaces?

Let's say (hypothetically) I want to route `/usr/bin/thunderbird` through `vlan0` but `/usr/bin/firefox` through `eth0`.

Is there a way? And if so, is there a graphical tool for it as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier solution is a custom routing to specific hosts, in your example, to your mail server.

Answer (score 1):

Routing is done at IP level, which doesn't know anything about applications that are generating traffic. So I don't think it's possible.

Comment: How is it possible then that with netstat -p you can see the program behind a specific network connection?